# trouble linking with glfw using premake and vs2019

Tags: c++, glfw, premake

I am trying to build a simple project using premake 5. On win10 using visual studio 2019.
Premake is new for me, but I start simple : the only dependencies are glm ( headers only library), GLAD, and GLFW.
I included GLAD and GLFW as subprojects in my premake file.
Project generation goes fine.

glm is correctly included and usable.

When building :
GLAD and GLFW build correctly to their respective .lib files
But the "core" application fails with these linker errors :

```
3>GLFW.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSelectPlatform referenced in function glfwInit
3>GLFW.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwPlatformLoadModule referenced in function _glfwInitVulkan
3>GLFW.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwPlatformFreeModule referenced in function _glfwInitVulkan
3>GLFW.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwPlatformGetModuleSymbol referenced in function _glfwInitVulkan
```

I must be missing a config option when building glfw

Here is the premake lua script responsible for building GLFW :

```
project "GLFW"
kind "StaticLib"
language "C"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
    "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
    "src/glfw_config.h",
    "src/context.c",
    "src/init.c",
    "src/input.c",
    "src/monitor.c",
    "src/vulkan.c",
    "src/window.c"
}
filter "system:linux"
    pic "On"

    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"

    files
    {
        "src/x11_init.c",
        "src/x11_monitor.c",
        "src/x11_window.c",
        "src/xkb_unicode.c",
        "src/posix_time.c",
        "src/posix_thread.c",
        "src/glx_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
        "src/linux_joystick.c"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_GLFW_X11"
        
    }

filter "system:windows"
    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"
    
    -- buildoptions{
    --     "/MT"
    -- }

    files
    {
        "src/win32_init.c",
        "src/win32_joystick.c",
        "src/win32_monitor.c",
        "src/win32_time.c",
        "src/win32_thread.c",
        "src/win32_window.c",
        "src/wgl_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c"
    }

    defines 
    { 
        "_GLFW_WIN32",
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"

    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "On"
```

Comment: If your goal is to make a project using glfw, you are better of using CMake

Comment: Two of the missing functions are in `win32_module.c`. I suggest you figure out the rest [for yourself](https://github.com/glfw/glfw).

Comment: thank you for the tip. Adding win32_module.c to glfw project files got rid of 3 of the errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to 'Botje' comment, I realized there was a bunch of missing files in the premake script. (I got this file from another project and wrongly assumed it was correct )

I found the missing files when looking into CMakeLists.txt present in glfw project source directory.

here is the new lua premake script for glfw project :

```
project "GLFW"
kind "StaticLib"
language "C"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
    "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
    "src/internal.h",
    "src/platform.h",
    "src/mappings.h",
    "src/context.c",
    "src/init.c",
    "src/input.c",
    "src/monitor.c",
    "src/platform.c",
    "src/vulkan.c",
    "src/window.c",
    "src/egl_context.c",
    "src/osmesa_context.c",
    "src/null_platform.h",
    "src/null_joystick.h",
    "src/null_init.c",

    "src/null_monitor.c",
    "src/null_window.c",
    "src/null_joystick.c",

}
filter "system:linux"
    pic "On"

    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"

    files
    {
        "src/x11_init.c",
        "src/x11_monitor.c",
        "src/x11_window.c",
        "src/xkb_unicode.c",
        "src/posix_time.c",
        "src/posix_thread.c",
        "src/glx_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
        "src/linux_joystick.c"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_GLFW_X11"
        
    }

filter "system:windows"
    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"
    
    -- buildoptions{
    --     "/MT"
    -- }

    files
    {
        "src/win32_init.c",
        "src/win32_module.c",
        "src/win32_joystick.c",
        "src/win32_monitor.c",
        "src/win32_time.h",
        "src/win32_time.c",
        "src/win32_thread.h",
        "src/win32_thread.c",
        "src/win32_window.c",
        "src/wgl_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c"
    }

    defines 
    { 
        "_GLFW_WIN32",
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"

    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "On"
```

Comment: Did you happen to get the premake file from [here](https://github.com/TheCherno/glfw)? This is where I got my premake file for GLFW and faced the same linking issues. It's weird that it works for their project and breaks for ours. Maybe we should raise an issue?